# debugging javascript in Visual Studio Web Express 2013 or Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015, visual-web-developer

In earlier versions of VS it was possible to use VS javascript debugger (which is awesome) to debug any website.  The "trick" was to create an empty web project, open IE within the instance of VS.   You could then just go to whatever page you wanted to debug and have full capacity of the debugger -- really handy when debugging more complicated apps.  I know this worked as recently as VS Web Developer Express 2008, but I am not able to get it working under either Web Express 2013 or VS 2015 Community.  I can't imagine they would remove this functionality, so I'm thinking I'm just doing it wrong.  For context, this link describes how it worked in older versions:

http://blog.berniesumption.com/software/how-to-debug-javascript-in-internet-explorer/

https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/ie-javascript-debugging-with-visual-studio-express-a-visual-guide/3768  (unfortunately images are missing from this one)

Comment: Why not just use the debugger built into the browser?

Comment: good question epascarello.  The debugger in visual studio is much more robust than the one in the browser.  Especially for some libraries (like backbone.js) which will sometimes fail silently and can be difficult to debug

Comment: Any update? d-coded:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could debug it in my side using the VS2015 with the "debugger" keyword in the JavaScript code.

Of course, please not enable the option "Disable Script debugging" in your IE setting.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response Jack Zhai.  Since there's always the possibility of needing to debug a page in production, it would be really nice if it could work the same way as the older versions (where debugger was not required) . But this is definitely a good thing to know! Thanks again!

Comment: @d-coded, that's the way I often debug the JS now, if it is helpful for you, please mark it as the answer, so it could help other members who meet the same issue as yours. Other suggestions using IE: https://forums.asp.net/t/2057128.aspx?How+to+debug+JavaScript. Have a nice day:)